# Dúvida com PHPUnit Testes-unitários

Tags: php, testes-de-unidade, phpunit

Galera estou iniciando com PHPUnit, estou implementando os primeiros testes em minhas aplicações porem estou com a seguinte duvida.

Realmente todas as classes devem ser testadas, ou existe algumas exceções, se sim quais são?

Por exemplo. Tenho uma estrutura MVC que implementa um sistema de rotas com as seguintes classes:

```
abstract class Bootstrap
{
    private $routes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->initRoutes();
        $this->run($this->getUrl());
    }

    abstract protected function initRoutes();

    protected function run($url)
    {
        array_walk($this->routes, function($route) use ($url){
            if($url == $route['route']){
                $class = "App\\Controllers\\".ucfirst($route['controller']);
                $controller = new $class;
                $action = $route['action'];
                $controller->$action();
            }
        });
    }

    protected function setRoutes(array $routes)
    {
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }

    protected function getUrl()
    {
       return parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    }
}
```

e...

```
class Route extends Bootstrap
{
    protected function initRoutes()
    {
        $routes['home'] = array(
            'route'     =>'/',
            'controller'=>'indexController',
            'action'    =>'index'
        );

        // Mais rotas..

        $this->setRoutes($routes);
    }
}
```

Essas classes precisam realmente ser testadas?. Se sim qual a maneira que eu possa implementar estes testes. Algum exemplo? Algo que possa ler? Pesquisei bastante porem não encontrei nada que solucionasse essa dúvida.

Comment: Essas classes aí são de algum framework ou você que implementou?

Comment: É um microframework desenvolvido para estudos!